# samba shares dissapear everynight

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, samba

I have ubuntu 8.04lts

and recently a weird problem has been cropping up. every night something happens and in the morning my coworkers cant see the shares. If i try to remote into the machine via ssh i don't get a prompt .

when i rebooted the machine i would get a "video cannot be displayed in this mode" screen and no other activity on the box.

I booted from grub into recovery and tried doing a package repair (keeping my smb.conf) and that didn't seem to do anything after a few other reboots I was able to get it to come up (im not sure what i did)

yesterday it did teh same thing

i booted to recovery then did a repair xserver and it came right up so i thought that resovled the issue but then today

same thing

anyone have any idea on what i can look for (im very new to linux in general)

worst case sennerio can i just reinstall ubuntu over again with out blowing out the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem.  Have you run diagnostics (such as with [Memtest86](http://www.memtest.org/))?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a hardware problem (+1) to mr Cry Havok

It was a combo of a bad psu and a bad cooling fan on a agpx8 video card. the finally clue came when i went into bois to see if anything was set funny and bois froze and i got a bunch of artifacts in the bois screen.